# CSS modules nested selectors

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have the following convention for name spacing my app and components:

```
<div id="app-name">

  <ul class="list">
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

---

```
#app-name {

  .list {
    margin: 0;
  }

}
```

I'd like to use CSS modules, however, I'm not sure how one would go about converting this and keep the same specificity of app and component name spacing. I understand I could simply omit the entire `#app-name` ID but I'd like this sort of specificity.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

You need to reference both `selectors` to the imported style module.

### App.tsx

```
import style from './App.module.scss';
function App() {
  return (
    <div id={style['app-name']}>
      <ul className={style.list}>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

### App.module.scss

```
#app-name {
  .list {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

This has been a [known issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/346) before, and they tried to create workarounds in order to achieve the desired output. Luckily this has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it works in all implementations but in Next.js you can prefix a css selector with `:global` to allow it to target a standard class name:

```css
#app-name {
  :global .list {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

[Credit to ctsstc on GitHub for discovering this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19417#discussioncomment-1443829).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing spicial, just nest your element the same way you nest your selectors

```
// style.module.scss
.container {
  .list {
    .item {
      background: red;
    } 
  }
}

// component.tsx
import styles from './style.module.scss';

export MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.list}>
      <div className={styles.item}>
       Hello :-)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score -3):

**Try This**

```
#app-name .list {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

**Snippet Example Below**

```css
 #app-name .list {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="app-name">

  <ul class="list">
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: That's actually what I do have, however, I wanted to separate them for reference here as, ideally, the #app-name can have many nested "component" styles: .list, .another-list, etc.

The same issue resides...